# WPF DataGrid Filtering affects referential integrity when deleting records

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, wpfdatagrid, observablecollection

This issue has been difficult to track down. I use an ObservableCollection for my DataGrid:

**Observable Collection Creation**

```
_claims = new ObservableCollection<Claim>(
                            _context.Claims.Include("Inventory").Where(c => c.Id == claimID));
    ...
_claimInventoryViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("claimViewSource")));
_claimInventoryViewSource.Source = _claims;
```

I can delete as many records in the DataGrid as desired without issue (as it is), but after filtering  (code below), then deleting an item, something happens to the collection. When I delete another record I get this error:

> The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error
>   occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be
>   in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: A referential
>   integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that
>   define the referential constraints are not consistent between
>   principal and dependent objects in the relationship.

**Delete Code:**

```
Inventory inventoryItem = inventoryDataGrid.SelectedItem as Inventory;
Int32 selectedIndex = inventoryDataGrid.SelectedIndex;

if (selectedIndex == inventoryDataGrid.Items.Count - 1)
    selectedIndex--;

_context.Inventory.DeleteObject(inventoryItem);
```

**Filtering Code:**

```
private void inventoryGrid_Filter(object sender, System.Windows.Data.FilterEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item is Inventory)
                e.Accepted = (e.Item as Inventory).Description != null && (e.Item as Inventory).Description.ToUpper().Contains(txtFindItem.Text.ToUpper())
                     || (e.Item as Inventory).Source != null && (e.Item as Inventory).Source.ToUpper().Contains(txtFindItem.Text.ToUpper())
            else
                e.Accepted = true;
        }

private void RefreshList()
        {
            if (inventoryDataGrid.Items is CollectionView)
            {
                CollectionViewSource csv = (CollectionViewSource)FindResource("claimInventoryViewSource");
                if (csv != null)
                    csv.View.Refresh();
            }
        }
```

Hope this is clear enough, thanks in Advance!

Comment: Solution: Remove Data Access code from code behind. Create a proper layered application.

Comment: @HighCore, thank you for the suggestion. This could be a solution, however I have invested many hours into this project, following technical books from "professionals" who gave me the inspiration and ideas to make it the way it is. My code didn't come together by chance and I was simply trying to model "the pros" in the way that they did theirs. I now have almost 13,000 lines of code wrapped up in this which is also in production daily. What should I do?

Comment: @HighCore, Should I start over from scratch to make a "proper layered application" and surprise my customer with a large, unexpected invoice, for making a more efficient, "properly" designed app in order to address one glaring error that happens every so often? Is this what you are recommending?

Comment: 13,000 lines of code in `Window1.xaml.cs`. Nice. No, I'm afraid I cannot give you any solution to your problem.